# Upgrading Elixir project with Edeliver error: {:no_matching_relup, '0.1.0+35132c2', '0.1.0+ba8eb26'}

Tags: elixir, edeliver

I am trying to upgrade my Elixir application with `edeliver upgrade`,
but an error appears: `{:no_matching_relup, '0.1.0+35132c2', '0.1.0+ba8eb26'}`

In cmd: `mix edeliver upgrade production --verbose --with=0.1.0`

`AUTO_VERSION` is set to `git-revision`

`RELEASE_VERSION` is set to `0.1.0`

Comment: Looks like you have not pushed the last commit.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

1. remove `RELEASE_VERSION` from `edeliver/.config` file
2. get current version with `mix edeliver version`
3. use `mix edeliver build upgrade --with=current-version --auto-version=git-revision` with `mix edeliver deploy upgrade` instead of `mix edeliver upgrade`

useful source: http://www.petecorey.com/blog/2017/01/23/upgrade-releases-with-edeliver/